# Can I have this migration-rejected q unlocked?

Tags: support, closed-questions, migration

[Why are some Covid-19 tests excluded in some US states?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52927/why-are-some-covid-19-tests-excluded-in-some-us-states)

The P.SE-mod-decided migration was rejected for a good reason by the Med.SE mod. I agree with the latter that the answer to the q almost certainly isn't a medical rationale, but probably has something to do with state regulations.... which is why I asked on P.SE in the first place.

Unfortunately, I can't even flag the q here now, because the flag goes to Med SE, still. So, I'm asking here (on meta) for the q to be re-opened here, on P.SE.

I see I can edit the q here [though the history page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/52927/revisions), but I can't flag for mod or vote to reopen from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why Medical Science Stack Exchange thinks that they would be worse at answering questions about a disease testing than us. Perhaps they are just sick of Covid-19 questions? Anyway, I reopend the question.

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious how you were able to do that. If I click on the q link on the main page it still goes to the [deleted med SE page](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23330/why-are-some-covid-19-tests-excluded-in-some-us-states). Hopefully that aspect it will get sorted by itself.

Comment: @Fizz Migrated questions use a 301 Redirect which is likely cached by your browser.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: you're right, in a different browser it loads ok now.